# How to upload paid app using IAP in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to upload paid app on `iTunes Connect` means if you want to download the app then you have to pay first. For this do I need to implement `IAP`? I already integrated `IAP` so many times but inside the app. I want to know the process of uploading paid app on `iTunes Connect`. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No need of in-app purchase.

Comment: Thanks... but i how can i test as we used to test in app purchase using sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `In-App Purchase` for paid apps. Instead you have mention price in AppStore Connect.

Login in to **`App Store Connect`**. Open the app you want to make it paid. 
Go to the **`Pricing and Availability`**, in that select the price from **`Price Schedule`**

[image]

Please let me know if you have doubt.

Comment: Thanks @Arasuvel but one more thing i wanna know... How can i test this before publish on app store, or do we have any other way to test the app like sandbox?

Comment: It was not possible to test this, once apple approved and you have released the app. Then only it can be checked.